# Is it possible to define same variable twice in classic ASP?

Tags: variables, vbscript, asp-classic, declaration

Is it somehow possible to declare same variable in .asp file twice? Example below  does not look very clever, but this is just an **example** and I have to sort it out.

```
Dim number : number = 1

Select Case number
    Case 1
        Dim a
    Case 2
        Dim a
End Select
```

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically you can of course declare a variable twice, the problem is, asp will throw an error, if the variable is declared in the same scope.

whatever you want to achieve, keep in mind, you can (almost) always access the variables in parent scope, thus rendering a double declaration useless.

```
Dim number : number = 1
Dim a
Select Case number
   Case 1:
      a = "whatever"
   Case 2:
      a = "something different"
End Select
response.write a
```

Comment: Problem is, that i cannot declare those variables in parent scope. In fact, after case statements I have to include some files and those files have same variable declaration unfortunately. I thought that maybe there will be some method how to achieve this (for example in Java it is not a problem, i ihink...)

Comment: This isn't something I'd generally recommend, but you could always omit the "Option Explicit" statement and then you wouldn't need to declare your variables at all

Comment: @John just FYI that makes code quality slack of and greatly decreases maintainability, but i think this would generally be an option here.

Comment: @BigT why exactly can you not rename a? or `set a = nothing`

Comment: @BigT It sounds like your code is just one big mish-mash block.  Would it not be more sensible to encapsulate your code in `Sub`s or `Function`s?  That way your declarations will be retained and your code far more manageable.